# HMAC digest different in Java and C++

Tags: java, c++, cryptography, hmac, hmacsha1

I am trying to integrate 2 systems one uses C++ and other uses Jva for HMAC digest generation.

Following is C++ code:-

```
static const GUID seedGUID = { 0xd6fecf42, 0x2d1e, 0x4db9, { 0xa2, 0x73, 0xeb,
0x34, 0x13, 0xe, 0xa1, 0x37 } };
shaCheckSum.AddData((char*)&seedGUID, sizeof(seedGUID));
shaCheckSum.AddData((char*)szSeed, uiSeedLen);
shaCheckSum.AddData((char*)szStr, uiStrLen);
shaCheckSum.FinalDigest(szResult);
```

HMAC generated is 9B2D06D314018A5134EA1CF54D5A9F20CECC473965BD9801AAC9D4868EF39D38

szSeed is 0.4726005982213448
szStr is test@test.com

Following is Java code:-

```
    final String HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM = "HmacSha256";
    final String secret = "D6FECF42-2D1E-4db9-A273-EB34130EA137";
    final SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(secret.toLowerCase().getBytes(),HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
    final Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
    mac.init(signingKey);
    mac.update("0.4726005982213448".getBytes());
    mac.update("test@test.com".getBytes());
    final byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal();
    for (final byte element : rawHmac)
    {
       result += Integer.toString((element & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
    }
    System.out.println( result);
```

The result HMAC is f91b07623fea970b5f9d1f5d83f850b3a6077c0e80f42b574a01d861143eac09

Both the HMAC are different.

How can this issue be solved?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: What library is the C++ version using for the sha functionality?

Comment: Please respond on comments and answers, dear user...

Answer (score 3):

In the C++ version you are passing the bytes of the `seedGUID` while in the Java version, you are passing the binary encoding of the string representation of the guid. You should create a byte array in your Java version:

```
byte[] signingKey = new byte[]{ 0xd6, 0xfe, 0xcf, 0x42, 0x2d, 0x1e, 0x4d, 0xb9, 0xa2, 0x73, 0xeb, 0x34, 0x13, 0xe, 0xa1, 0x37 };
mac.init(signingKey);
```

You must also ensure you use the same encoding for the strings you encrypt. Your C++ version probably using ASCII characters, so you must specify the charset of the data:

```
mac.update("0.4726005982213448".getBytes("US-ASCII"));
mac.update("test@test.com".getBytes("US-ASCII"));
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Lee has written, I don't think that you are using [HMAC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2104.txt) at all in the C++ version. It looks to me that you use a SHA-? secure message digest directly (as hinted by the `FinalDigest()` method call). SHA-256 is *part* of the HMAC calculation, but just performing SHA-256 will definitely not create the same result.